# DrawCurve (GDI+) на Delphi 7

Tags: delphi-7, gdi+

Пытаюсь вызвать функцию `DrawCurve` из файла GDIPOBJ.pas. Фрагмент кода:

```
uses
  ..., GDIPAPI, GDIPOBJ;
...
const Points: array [0..3] of TGPPointF = (
    (X:  30.67; Y: 0),
    (X:  70.68; Y:  30),
    (X: 100.5; Y:  70),
    (X: 290.8; Y:  110));
var
  Pen: TGPPen;
  IGPG:  TGPGraphics;
begin
  IGPG := TGPGraphics.Create(Handle);
  Pen := TGPPen.Create(clBlue,2);

  IGPG.DrawCurve(Pen, Points, 4);  //  !!!!! [Error] There is no overloaded version of 'DrawCurve' that can be called with these arguments !!!!!
end;
```

Смотрим описание DrawCurve в файле GDIPOBJ.pas:

```
function TGPGraphics.DrawCurve(pen: TGPPen; points: PGPPointF; count: Integer): TStatus;
  begin
    result := SetStatus(GdipDrawCurve(nativeGraphics,
                           pen.nativePen, points,
                           count));
  end;
```

В функции выше я задаю TGPPen (Pen), PGPPointF (Points), Integer (4). Что не так?

Попробовал также выполнить напрямую через API-функцию:

```
GdipDrawCurve(IGPG, Pen, Points, 4);
```

Тут ругается на третий параметр:

> Incompatible types: 'Array' and 'PGPPointF'

Но ведь массив Points как раз-таки и состоит из PGPPointF...

Comment: `const Points` может быть преобразовано в  `PGPPointF`?

Comment: @VTT "Ну как я понимаю, то да, ибо в GDIPAPI.pas написано: `type
  PGPPointF = ^TGPPointF;
  TGPPointF = packed record
    X : Single;
    Y : Single;
  end;
  TPointFDynArray = array of TGPPointF;`

Comment: тогда скорее нет, короче попробуйте без const

Comment: @VTT без const не дает:"[Error] Unit1.pas(33): Unknown directive: 'Points'"

Comment: может вы в раздел переменных не перенесли?

Comment: @VTT если перенести объявление Points в var, то тогда будет ошибка "Cannot initialize local variables" (если без const); если же с const, то та же ошибка при вызове функции.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужен же указатель:

```
  PGPPointF(@Points[0])
```

Ещё ошибки - TGPGraphics требует использовать дескриптор графического контекста окна (Canvas), а не самого окна, и перу нужно указать непрозрачность (старший байт). Полный рабочий пример:

```
const Points: array [0..3] of TGPPointF = (
    (X:  30.67; Y: 0),
    (X:  70.68; Y:  30),
    (X: 100.5; Y:  70),
    (X: 290.8; Y:  110));
var
  Pen: TGPPen;
  IGPG:  TGPGraphics;
begin
  IGPG := TGPGraphics.Create(Canvas.Handle);
  Pen := TGPPen.Create($ff0000ff);
  try
    IGPG.DrawCurve(Pen, PGPPointF(@Points), 4);
  finally
    Pen.Free;
    IGPG.Free;
  end;
```

Comment: Благодарю! Получилось вот так: `IGPG.DrawCurve(Pen,PGPPointF(@Points[0]), Length(Points));` Только ничего не выводится :(

Comment: @UnityMan Добавил ещё поправки